# How to remove buttons in AnythingSlider and stop the sliding?

Tags: jquery

I'm currently using the anythingSlider it works quite well.

But if there is one **li**, how do i make it stop sliding and remove the buttons displayed below?

The **li**s are  generated from the database so sometimes there's only one. I want the buttons to show only when there is more then one image.

if there is one image all the buttons( back, forward, pause) should not be displayed.

Does anybody know of a way of stopping it sliding if there's only one **li** and removing the buttons when there is only one image.

=====================================================================================

Thank You. Currently I have the working version, posted below the old code is working.  I tried to replace it with yours it didnt seem to work. Is there something else that needs to be added?

```
function formatText(index, panel) {
return index + "";
}

$(function () {

$('.anythingSlider').anythingSlider({
easing: "easeInOutExpo", // Anything other than "linear" or "swing" requires the easing plugin
autoPlay: true, // This turns off the entire FUNCTIONALY, not just if it starts running or not.
delay: 7500, // How long between slide transitions in AutoPlay mode
startStopped: false, // If autoPlay is on, this can force it to start stopped
animationTime: 1250, // How long the slide transition takes
hashTags: true, // Should links change the hashtag in the URL?
buildNavigation: true, // If true, builds and list of anchor links to link to each slide
pauseOnHover: true, // If true, and autoPlay is enabled, the show will pause on hover
startText: "", // Start text
stopText: "", // Start text

navigationFormatter: formatText // Details at the top of the file on this use (advanced use)
});

$("#slide-jump").click(function(){
$('.anythingSlider').anythingSlider(6);
});
});


UPDATED WITH YOUR CODE :


function formatText(index, panel) {
return index + "";
}

$(function () {
 var singleSlide = true,
     options = {
      autoPlay: false,                // This turns off the entire FUNCTIONALY, not just if it starts running or not.
      buildNavigation: false,         // If true, builds and list of anchor links to link to each slide
      easing: "easeInOutExpo",        // Anything other than "linear" or "swing" requires the easing plugin
      delay: 3000,                    // How long between slide transitions in AutoPlay mode
      animationTime: 600,             // How long the slide transition takes
      hashTags: true,                 // Should links change the hashtag in the URL?
      pauseOnHover: true,             // If true, and autoPlay is enabled, the show will pause on hover
      navigationFormatter: formatText // Details at the top of the file on this use (advanced use)
    };

 // Add player options if more than one slide exists
 if ( $('.anythingSlider > div > ul > li').length > 1 ) {
  $.extend(options, {
   autoPlay: true,
   startStopped: false,     // If autoPlay is on, this can force it to start stopped
    startText: "", // Start text
    stopText: "", // Start text
   buildNavigation: true 
  });
  singleSlide = false;
 }

 // Initiate anythingSlider
     $("#slide-jump").click(function(){
    $('.anythingSlider').anythingSlider(6);
    });

 // hide anythingSlider navigation arrows
 if (singleSlide) { $('.anythingSlider a.arrow').hide(); }
});



HTML TAGS
```

=========================================================================================
Update  May 25 ,2010

When using

```
 $('.anythingSlider').anythingSlider(options);
```

instead of

```
 
$('.anythingSlider').anythingSlider(6);
```

the slider runs but I noticed that I get a Javascript Error :Object required
is there anything else I need to pass?
 Since before anythingSlider was taking 6 instead of options, where do I pass that 6, since its looking for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script. It should be added after any script (Ajax?) that loads your slider content.

```
$(function () {
 var singleSlide = true,
     options = {
      autoPlay: false,                // This turns off the entire FUNCTIONALY, not just if it starts running or not.
      buildNavigation: false,         // If true, builds and list of anchor links to link to each slide
      easing: "easeInOutExpo",        // Anything other than "linear" or "swing" requires the easing plugin
      delay: 3000,                    // How long between slide transitions in AutoPlay mode
      animationTime: 600,             // How long the slide transition takes
      hashTags: true,                 // Should links change the hashtag in the URL?
      pauseOnHover: true,             // If true, and autoPlay is enabled, the show will pause on hover
      navigationFormatter: formatText // Details at the top of the file on this use (advanced use)
    };

 // Add player options if more than one slide exists
 if ( $('.anythingSlider > div > ul > li').length > 1 ) {
  $.extend(options, {
   autoPlay: true,
   startStopped: false,     // If autoPlay is on, this can force it to start stopped
   startText: "Go",         // Start text
   stopText: "Stop",        // Stop text
   buildNavigation: true 
  });
  singleSlide = false;
 }

 // Initiate anythingSlider
 $('.anythingSlider').anythingSlider(options);

 // hide anythingSlider navigation arrows
 if (singleSlide) { $('.anythingSlider a.arrow').hide(); }
});
```

Personally, I think this should be built into the script...

---

**Update:**

Using the `$('.anythingSlider').anythingSlider(6);` format was intented for external links. I think the only way you could get that error is if you call that function before setting up the anythingSlider.

An alternative, which I don't think would make a difference, would be to call the slider change like this: `$('.anythingSlider').data('AnythingSlider').gotoPage(6);`

Comment: I tried to incorporate it but didnt work..is there anything else that needs to be added?

Thanks

Comment: It just breaks the carousel ie it just displays a frame/scrolling bar instead of the carosel when I plug that in.

Comment: I posted a demo for you (http://jsfiddle.net/66s6w/). It's set up to show two items, but if you comment out one of them and run the script again, you should see the script in action. So I can only guess that if the demo works for you, then there is something else going on in your code.

Comment: When using
<pre>
 $('.anythingSlider').anythingSlider(options);

</pre>
instead of
<pre>
 
$('.anythingSlider').anythingSlider(6);

</pre>
the slider runs but I noticed that I get a Javascript Error :Object required is there anything else I need to pass? Since before anythingSlider was taking 6 instead of options, where do I pass that 6, since it may be looking for it perhaps?

Comment: I just forked the plugin with a fix so it won't show the navigation or player controls when there is only one page, check it out here: http://github.com/Mottie/AnythingSlider